# vocal software for singing in tune

Tags: voice, software, voice-training

I have problem with singing in tune. I'm looking for a software that could recognize live when I'm out of tune and show me how far I am from the right note.
I have two questions:

1. Has anyone used a software like this and could recommend it to me?
2. Is there any software that can identify the exact vocal notes from a song?

Comment: There is software that does such things, but frankly, the only _proper_ way to sing in tune is to hear it yourself. Just practise, sing to accompaniment (playing some simple guitar chords goes a long way), join a choir or band... obviously, taking a few vocal lessons can't be a bad idea either. You'll get a much better feeling for when you're off these ways. Or if you don't, then singing is perhaps just not your thing – you can still play an instrument!

Comment: I agree with @leftaroundabout. It is not the way to learn singing in tune. The way to learn that is to use proper technique and listening.

Comment: Similar questions: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33285/singing-on-pitch-with-visual-cues/33289#33289, http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22005/how-do-i-know-when-im-singing-in-key/22023#22023, http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/178/what-are-the-most-effective-ear-training-methods/180#180

Answer (score 1):

Software like Antares Autotune Live keeps you in tune but as commenters noted too, it might be more useful to study to get your technique better.

If you'd just like to see how far you're off (for practicing purposes as an example), it could be an idea to get the Reaper DAW (http://reaper.fm/). This DAW comes with a plugin named "ReaTune" and will display exactly what note is being sent into it, along with how much you need to go up or down:

[image: Reaper's ReaTune preview]

Since the people that produce Reaper have a really nice policy on being able to use their product without paying for it, it might be an idea to try it out. It will most definitely help you in improving your vocal technique.